# Right align button in form

Tags: html, css, alignment, bootstrap-4

I'm having some trouble using float: right; on a button.

Whatever I do, the button just doesn't wanna go to the right.
It's the second button, the one with the "advanced-search-button" class.

I'm using Bootstrap 4.

**HTML**

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="box">
    <div class="box-title w-100">
        <h5>Opgaver</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="box-form w-100">
        <form action="" class="form-inline">
            <div class="form-group form-group-custom">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Rekvirent">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group form-group-custom">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Tildelt til">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group form-group-custom">
                <select name="select_Afsluttet" id="select_Afsluttet" class="custom-select mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
                    <option selected hidden value="">Afsluttet</option>
                    <option value="">Ja</option>
                    <option value="">Nej</option>
                    <option value="">Alle</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group form-group-custom">
                <select name="select_Godkendt" id="select_Godkendt" class="custom-select mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
                    <option selected hidden value="">Godkendt</option>
                    <option value="">Ja</option>
                    <option value="">Nej</option>
                    <option value="">Alle</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group form-group-custom float-sm-right">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" style="margin-right: 15px;">Søg</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm advanced-search-button" onclick="advancedSearch(this)">Avanceret søgning</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        <form action="" class="form-inline form-custom advanced-search">
            <div class="form-group form-group-custom">
                <select name="select_Prioritet" id="select_Prioritet" class="custom-select mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
                    <option selected hidden value="">Prioritet</option>
                    <option value="">Lav</option>
                    <option value="">Middel</option>
                    <option value="">Høj</option>
                    <option value="">Straks</option>
                    <option value="">Driftfejl</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group form-group-custom">
                <select name="select_Opgavestatus" id="select_Opgavestatus" class="custom-select mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
                    <option selected hidden value="">Opgavestatus</option>
                    <option value="">Arkiveret</option>
                    <option value="">Sendt til DUC</option>
                    <option value="">Venter på bruger</option>
                    <option value="">Venter på kunde</option>
                    <option value="">Venter på AO</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group form-group-custom">
                <select name="select_Opgavetype" id="select_Opgavetype" class="custom-select mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
                    <option selected hidden value="">Opgavetype</option>
                    <option value="">Andet</option>
                    <option value="">Sendt til DUC</option>
                    <option value="">Venter på bruger</option>
                    <option value="">Venter på kunde</option>
                    <option value="">Venter på AO</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group form-group-custom">
                <select name="select_Underkategori" id="select_Underkategori" class="custom-select mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
                    <option selected hidden value="">Underkategori</option>
                    <option value="">Via telefon</option>
                    <option value="">Via email</option>
                    <option value="">Internet</option>
                    <option value="">Intranet</option>
                    <option value="">VMS</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group form-group-custom">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Søg efter">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="box-content">
        <table class="table table-hover table-sm">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Dato</th>
                    <th scope="col">ID</th>
                    <th scope="col">Rekv</th>
                    <th scope="col">Tildelt</th>
                    <th scope="col">Beskrivelse</th>
                    <th scope="col">Type</th>
                    <th scope="col">Seneste log besked</th>
                    <th scope="col">Deadline</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>22-11-2017</td>
                    <td>70935</td>
                    <td>HJR</td>
                    <td>LUC</td>
                    <td>Docking Station...</td>
                    <td>Bestilling - Via Telefon</td>
                    <td>8 dage</td>
                    <td>22-11-2017</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>28-11-2017</td>
                    <td>71049</td>
                    <td>LLJ</td>
                    <td>LUC</td>
                    <td>Kan ikke scanne fra sin printe....</td>
                    <td>IT-Drift - Via Telefon</td>
                    <td>3 dage</td>
                    <td>28-11-2017</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>05-12-2017</td>
                    <td>71244</td>
                    <td>LYL</td>
                    <td>LUC</td>
                    <td>Printer med gul baggrund på hy....</td>
                    <td>IT-support - Via Telefon</td>
                    <td>1 dage</td>
                    <td>05-12-2017</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>05-12-2017</td>
                    <td>71244</td>
                    <td>LYL</td>
                    <td>LUC</td>
                    <td>Printer med gul baggrund på hy....</td>
                    <td>IT-support - Via Telefon</td>
                    <td>1 dage</td>
                    <td>05-12-2017</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>05-12-2017</td>
                    <td>71244</td>
                    <td>LYL</td>
                    <td>LUC</td>
                    <td>Printer med gul baggrund på hy....</td>
                    <td>IT-support - Via Telefon</td>
                    <td>1 dage</td>
                    <td>05-12-2017</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>05-12-2017</td>
                    <td>71244</td>
                    <td>LYL</td>
                    <td>LUC</td>
                    <td>Printer med gul baggrund på hy....</td>
                    <td>IT-support - Via Telefon</td>
                    <td>1 dage</td>
                    <td>05-12-2017</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>05-12-2017</td>
                    <td>71244</td>
                    <td>LYL</td>
                    <td>LUC</td>
                    <td>Printer med gul baggrund på hy....</td>
                    <td>IT-support - Via Telefon</td>
                    <td>1 dage</td>
                    <td>05-12-2017</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>05-12-2017</td>
                    <td>71244</td>
                    <td>LYL</td>
                    <td>LUC</td>
                    <td>Printer med gul baggrund på hy....</td>
                    <td>IT-support - Via Telefon</td>
                    <td>1 dage</td>
                    <td>05-12-2017</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>05-12-2017</td>
                    <td>71244</td>
                    <td>LYL</td>
                    <td>LUC</td>
                    <td>Printer med gul baggrund på hy....</td>
                    <td>IT-support - Via Telefon</td>
                    <td>1 dage</td>
                    <td>05-12-2017</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>05-12-2017</td>
                    <td>71244</td>
                    <td>LYL</td>
                    <td>LUC</td>
                    <td>Printer med gul baggrund på hy....</td>
                    <td>IT-support - Via Telefon</td>
                    <td>1 dage</td>
                    <td>05-12-2017</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>05-12-2017</td>
                    <td>71244</td>
                    <td>LYL</td>
                    <td>LUC</td>
                    <td>Printer med gul baggrund på hy....</td>
                    <td>IT-support - Via Telefon</td>
                    <td>1 dage</td>
                    <td>05-12-2017</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>05-12-2017</td>
                    <td>71244</td>
                    <td>LYL</td>
                    <td>LUC</td>
                    <td>Printer med gul baggrund på hy....</td>
                    <td>IT-support - Via Telefon</td>
                    <td>1 dage</td>
                    <td>05-12-2017</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>05-12-2017</td>
                    <td>71244</td>
                    <td>LYL</td>
                    <td>LUC</td>
                    <td>Printer med gul baggrund på hy....</td>
                    <td>IT-support - Via Telefon</td>
                    <td>1 dage</td>
                    <td>05-12-2017</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>05-12-2017</td>
                    <td>71244</td>
                    <td>LYL</td>
                    <td>LUC</td>
                    <td>Printer med gul baggrund på hy....</td>
                    <td>IT-support - Via Telefon</td>
                    <td>1 dage</td>
                    <td>05-12-2017</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

I hope you can help me :)

I don't have any custom CSS for this part, I only use the classes for JS.

Comment: add class to your button tag  `float-right`

Comment: @Ylama I've already done that, for the ease of showing it on here, I just have it in the HTMl as "style="float: right;"

Comment: thought you did not want to use custom css only `classes`.

Comment: @Ylama Nope, I just don't have any right now, so people don't get confused as to why there is no CSS on the post.

Comment: wel then for class `form-group` style it as `inline-block` , and on the `.btn-success` add `float: left` , adn on the `btn-primary` add `float: right;`

Comment: posted an answer have a look

Comment: so you dont want it on a new line just to float right ?

Comment: That's exactly what I want.

Comment: `<div class="form-group col-sm-9 d-inline-block form-group-custom float-left">` these classes might help you for that div...Maybe not exactly what you want but you get the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this with the **Flexbox**:

```css
.flex-container {display:flex} /* displays children inline by default */

.flex-item {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between; /* horizontal alignment / creates the max. horizontal space between the buttons */
 flex: 1 !important; /* takes all the remaining horizontal space / needs to have the !important keyword otherwise it doesn't work */
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="box">
            <div class="box-title w-100">
                <h5>Opgaver</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="box-form w-100">
                <form action="" class="form-inline flex-container">
                    <div class="form-group form-group-custom">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Rekvirent">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group form-group-custom">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Tildelt til">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group form-group-custom">
                        <select name="select_Afsluttet" id="select_Afsluttet" class="custom-select mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
                            <option selected hidden value="">Afsluttet</option>
                            <option value="">Ja</option>
                            <option value="">Nej</option>
                            <option value="">Alle</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group form-group-custom">
                        <select name="select_Godkendt" id="select_Godkendt" class="custom-select mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
                            <option selected hidden value="">Godkendt</option>
                            <option value="">Ja</option>
                            <option value="">Nej</option>
                            <option value="">Alle</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group form-group-custom flex-item">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" style="margin-right: 15px;">Søg</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm advanced-search-button" onclick="advancedSearch(this)">Avanceret søgning</button>
                    </div>
                </form>

                <form action="" class="form-inline form-custom advanced-search">
                    <div class="form-group form-group-custom">
                        <select name="select_Prioritet" id="select_Prioritet" class="custom-select mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
                            <option selected hidden value="">Prioritet</option>
                            <option value="">Lav</option>
                            <option value="">Middel</option>
                            <option value="">Høj</option>
                            <option value="">Straks</option>
                            <option value="">Driftfejl</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group form-group-custom">
                        <select name="select_Opgavestatus" id="select_Opgavestatus" class="custom-select mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
                            <option selected hidden value="">Opgavestatus</option>
                            <option value="">Arkiveret</option>
                            <option value="">Sendt til DUC</option>
                            <option value="">Venter på bruger</option>
                            <option value="">Venter på kunde</option>
                            <option value="">Venter på AO</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group form-group-custom">
                        <select name="select_Opgavetype" id="select_Opgavetype" class="custom-select mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
                            <option selected hidden value="">Opgavetype</option>
                            <option value="">Andet</option>
                            <option value="">Sendt til DUC</option>
                            <option value="">Venter på bruger</option>
                            <option value="">Venter på kunde</option>
                            <option value="">Venter på AO</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group form-group-custom">
                        <select name="select_Underkategori" id="select_Underkategori" class="custom-select mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
                            <option selected hidden value="">Underkategori</option>
                            <option value="">Via telefon</option>
                            <option value="">Via email</option>
                            <option value="">Internet</option>
                            <option value="">Intranet</option>
                            <option value="">VMS</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group form-group-custom">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Søg efter">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

            <div class="box-content">
                <table class="table table-hover table-sm">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Dato</th>
                        <th scope="col">ID</th>
                        <th scope="col">Rekv</th>
                        <th scope="col">Tildelt</th>
                        <th scope="col">Beskrivelse</th>
                        <th scope="col">Type</th>
                        <th scope="col">Seneste log besked</th>
                        <th scope="col">Deadline</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>22-11-2017</td>
                        <td>70935</td>
                        <td>HJR</td>
                        <td>LUC</td>
                        <td>Docking Station...</td>
                        <td>Bestilling - Via Telefon</td>
                        <td>8 dage</td>
                        <td>22-11-2017</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>28-11-2017</td>
                        <td>71049</td>
                        <td>LLJ</td>
                        <td>LUC</td>
                        <td>Kan ikke scanne fra sin printe....</td>
                        <td>IT-Drift - Via Telefon</td>
                        <td>3 dage</td>
                        <td>28-11-2017</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>05-12-2017</td>
                        <td>71244</td>
                        <td>LYL</td>
                        <td>LUC</td>
                        <td>Printer med gul baggrund på hy....</td>
                        <td>IT-support - Via Telefon</td>
                        <td>1 dage</td>
                        <td>05-12-2017</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>05-12-2017</td>
                        <td>71244</td>
                        <td>LYL</td>
                        <td>LUC</td>
                        <td>Printer med gul baggrund på hy....</td>
                        <td>IT-support - Via Telefon</td>
                        <td>1 dage</td>
                        <td>05-12-2017</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>05-12-2017</td>
                        <td>71244</td>
                        <td>LYL</td>
                        <td>LUC</td>
                        <td>Printer med gul baggrund på hy....</td>
                        <td>IT-support - Via Telefon</td>
                        <td>1 dage</td>
                        <td>05-12-2017</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>05-12-2017</td>
                        <td>71244</td>
                        <td>LYL</td>
                        <td>LUC</td>
                        <td>Printer med gul baggrund på hy....</td>
                        <td>IT-support - Via Telefon</td>
                        <td>1 dage</td>
                        <td>05-12-2017</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>05-12-2017</td>
                        <td>71244</td>
                        <td>LYL</td>
                        <td>LUC</td>
                        <td>Printer med gul baggrund på hy....</td>
                        <td>IT-support - Via Telefon</td>
                        <td>1 dage</td>
                        <td>05-12-2017</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>05-12-2017</td>
                        <td>71244</td>
                        <td>LYL</td>
                        <td>LUC</td>
                        <td>Printer med gul baggrund på hy....</td>
                        <td>IT-support - Via Telefon</td>
                        <td>1 dage</td>
                        <td>05-12-2017</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>05-12-2017</td>
                        <td>71244</td>
                        <td>LYL</td>
                        <td>LUC</td>
                        <td>Printer med gul baggrund på hy....</td>
                        <td>IT-support - Via Telefon</td>
                        <td>1 dage</td>
                        <td>05-12-2017</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>05-12-2017</td>
                        <td>71244</td>
                        <td>LYL</td>
                        <td>LUC</td>
                        <td>Printer med gul baggrund på hy....</td>
                        <td>IT-support - Via Telefon</td>
                        <td>1 dage</td>
                        <td>05-12-2017</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>05-12-2017</td>
                        <td>71244</td>
                        <td>LYL</td>
                        <td>LUC</td>
                        <td>Printer med gul baggrund på hy....</td>
                        <td>IT-support - Via Telefon</td>
                        <td>1 dage</td>
                        <td>05-12-2017</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>05-12-2017</td>
                        <td>71244</td>
                        <td>LYL</td>
                        <td>LUC</td>
                        <td>Printer med gul baggrund på hy....</td>
                        <td>IT-support - Via Telefon</td>
                        <td>1 dage</td>
                        <td>05-12-2017</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>05-12-2017</td>
                        <td>71244</td>
                        <td>LYL</td>
                        <td>LUC</td>
                        <td>Printer med gul baggrund på hy....</td>
                        <td>IT-support - Via Telefon</td>
                        <td>1 dage</td>
                        <td>05-12-2017</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>05-12-2017</td>
                        <td>71244</td>
                        <td>LYL</td>
                        <td>LUC</td>
                        <td>Printer med gul baggrund på hy....</td>
                        <td>IT-support - Via Telefon</td>
                        <td>1 dage</td>
                        <td>05-12-2017</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I've made it to work by adding two additional classes (`.flex-container` & `.flex-item`) and applying certain *flex* properties with appropriate values.

I applied the `.flex-container` class to the `form` element which is the parent of all the `.form-group` / `.form-group-custom` div's, and the `.flex-item` class to the parent of the `button`s.

Comment: This semi works, it messes everything else up in the form.
It's an Inline row, so everything is on the same line, by adding 100% width it makes the inline not work.

Comment: I've added all the HTML this time :)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="box-form w-100">
<form action="" class="">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-9 d-inline-block form-group-custom float-left">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success float-left  btn-sm" style="margin-right: 15px;">Søg</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary float-right  btn-sm advanced-search-button" onclick="advancedSearch(this)">Avanceret søgning</button>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

Removed the class `form-inline` form and added `w-100` for the first `div` within form.

Comment: This doesn't work either. I've updated the post with all the HTML code if you're wanting to have a go at it.

Comment: look at my update i added to new classes `w-100 d-inline-block form-inline` which means you dont need to remove `form-inline`

Comment: Updated please have a look.

Comment: i tried it within your code snippet and it did not create an new row.. are you sure you implementing this correct.

Comment: Create a new snippet, with the NEW html I posted up there like 30 mins ago, and you'll see that it creates a new row.

Comment: Cause from the snippet you posted, it's still using the old HTML.

Answer (score 0):

U can as well use the CSS property of top n left.  Set the values in pixel.  And the button should have a position property value to absolute.  It worked for mine.

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Comment: .leftButton{ position: absolute; font-size: 20px; top: 4.3%; left: 86%; height: 30px; width: 14%;}.   Leftbutton is the classname of the button

Comment: Wouldn't adding position: absolute; remove the responsive layout of the website?
Especially when you say top 4,3% and left 86%

Comment: U can change the percentage values to pixels so the buttons position doesn't change with changes to screen size.

Comment: Yeah, this just messed up the whole button.

Comment: U have to change the values of top and left till it reaches the desired location on your page. Its like changing coordinates on a graph. Keep changing the left n top values till the location suits your page.

Comment: But what if I resize the page, then it's totally out of place?

Comment: If its for mobile use fixed positioning with values of pixel. If u want the position to respond to resizing use values of percentage. The code I showed u I used it for my website. I used % for the desktop n laptop version. But for mobiles use values of pixels. Mobiles generally have the same pixel width.